# Update the Listbox/Treeview instead of creating a new one each time

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tree, listbox

I'm trying to display pieces of information from a CSV in a tabular manner using a `ttk.TreeView`. The code does exactly what I want it to do. I just
want to update the tree each time I click on the first `Curselec_Croq` `Listbox`
and not create a new tree each time I click.

How could I do that?

```
import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()
import sys
import csv
sys.version_info

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *

def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):  ## We use here ";" to parse CSV
                                          ## because of the European way of
    csv_data = []                         ## dealing with excel-csv
    for line in content.split('\n'):      ## strips spaces also
        csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split( delimiter )] )
    return csv_data

global car_header
global car_list

class McListBox(object):
    """use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.tree = None
        self._setup_widgets()
        self._build_tree()

    def _setup_widgets(self):
        s ='""'
        msg = ttk.Label(wraplength="4i", justify="left", anchor="n",
            padding=(10, 2, 10, 6))
        msg.pack(fill='x')

        container = ttk.Frame()
        container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # create a treeview with dual scrollbars
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=car_header, show="headings")
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",
            command=self.tree.yview)
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal",
            command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
            xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=container)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=container)
        hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew', in_=container)

        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def _build_tree(self):
        for col in car_header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
                command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,
                width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in car_list:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(car_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(car_header[ix], width=col_w)


def sortby(tree, col, descending):
    """sort tree contents when a column header is clicked on"""
    # grab values to sort
    data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) \
        for child in tree.get_children('')]
    # if the data to be sorted is numeric change to float
    #data =  change_numeric(data)
    # now sort the data in place
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    for ix, item in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(item[1], '', ix)
    # switch the heading so it will sort in the opposite direction
    tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: sortby(tree, col,
                                                     int(not descending)))

Remplissage = parse_csv(
                open('Remplissage.csv', 'rU', encoding="ISO-8859-1").read())
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Visualizer")

def CurSelet_croq(evt):
    global car_header
    global car_list

    car_header = [
        'Used Nutrients in the Profession',
        'Nutrients used in this PetFood (Source : Official Website)']
    car_list=[]
    value=str(liste_croq.get(liste_croq.curselection()))
    for i in range(0,len(Remplissage)):
        if Remplissage[i][0]=="Name":
           for j in range(1,len(Remplissage[i])):
               if Remplissage[i][j]==value:
                   for k in range(0,len(Remplissage)-1):
                       if Remplissage[k][j]!="ND":
                           car_list.append([Remplissage[k][0],"OK"])
                       else:
                           car_list.append([Remplissage[k][0],""])

    print(car_list)
    mc_listbox = McListBox()
    return car_header, car_list

liste_croq = Listbox(root,width=70, height=10)
for i in range(0,len(Remplissage)):
               if Remplissage[i][0]=="Name":
                  for j in range(1,len(Remplissage[i])):
                      liste_croq.insert(i,Remplissage[i][j])
                      liste_croq.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', CurSelet_croq)
                      liste_croq.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So far I've tried to create a new `root` window each time and destroy the previous one but it just look like it. It's not quite "updating".

Any help'd be appreciated.

As Martineau requested it here is an extract of `Remplissage.csv`

```
Name;Puppy Small Breed For Small Breed Puppies weighing 9 KG (20 LBS) at maturity;Puppy & Junior For puppies between 9 and 25;Puppy Large Breed For Puppies 25;Adult Small Breed For Small Breed Dogs 1 Year and Older;Chicken & Burbank Potato For All Breeds and Life Stages
Methionine;0.6%;0.6%;0.6%
Metabolisable energy (calculated according NRC85);ND;ND;ND
Moisture,Water,Humidity,Moisture (max.);10%;10%;10%
```

Comment: have you read any [documentation on the treeview widget](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-treeview)? There are documented methods for adding, deleting, and modifying items.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Actually i'm a bit lost here. Could you be me more specific on what you think i should do. I took a deep look to what you suggested me and i didn't know how i could adapt my code with those informations.EDIT  : I could use `delete` to get rid of a tree when a new is creating but i don't understand exactly how i could do that. Indeed, i can't access `tree`when i get out of the `McListBox` class.

Comment: Please add some example CSV data to your question.

Comment: The question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer :

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *
def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):  ##We use here ";" to parse CSV because of the European way of dealing with excel-csv
  csv_data = []
  for line in content.split('\n'):
    csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split( delimiter )] ) # strips spaces also
  return csv_data

canvas=parse_csv(open('canvas.csv','rU',encoding="ISO-8859-1").read())
#fediaf_requirements is a list containing where fediaf has a 
fediaf_requirements=[]
for i in range(0,len(canvas)):
               if canvas[i][1]=="FEDIAF":
                  fediaf_requirements.append(canvas[i][0])

car_header = ['Used Nutrients in the Profession', 'Nutrients used in this PetFood (Source : Official Website)', 'FEDIAF Requirement']


#Create the Data to be put into the table
def FromCSV_to_Tree(liste_croq):
    global car_list
    car_list=[]
    value=str(liste_croq.get(liste_croq.curselection()))
    for i in range(0,len(Remplissage)):
               if Remplissage[i][0]=="Name":
                  for j in range(1,len(Remplissage[i])):
                      if Remplissage[i][j]==value:
                          for k in range(0,len(Remplissage)-1):
                              if Remplissage[k][0] in fediaf_requirements :
                                  a="Required"
                              else :
                                  a=""


                              if Remplissage[k][j]!="ND":
                                     car_list.append([Remplissage[k][0],"OK",a])
                              else:
                                  car_list.append([Remplissage[k][0],"",a])



def CurSelet_croq(evt,container):
    global car_list
    FromCSV_to_Tree(liste_croq)
    car_header = ['Used Nutrients in the Profession', 'Nutrients used in this PetFood (Source : Official Website)', 'FEDIAF Requirement']
    print(car_list)


    #create a treeview with dual scrollbars

    #Container and container.pack detached to update the tree with the new datas. 
    container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)




    tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=car_header, show="headings")
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",
                        command=tree.yview)
    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal",
                        command=tree.xview)
    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
                   xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
    tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=container)
    vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=container)
    hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew', in_=container)

    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def sortby(tree, col, descending):
        """sort tree contents when a column header is clicked on"""
        # grab values to sort
        data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) \
            for child in tree.get_children('')]
        # if the data to be sorted is numeric change to float
        #data =  change_numeric(data)
        # now sort the data in place
        data.sort(reverse=descending)
        for ix, item in enumerate(data):
            tree.move(item[1], '', ix)
        # switch the heading so it will sort in the opposite direction
        tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: sortby(tree, col, \

            int(not descending)))

##Put data into the tree
    for col in car_header:
        tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
                     command=lambda c=col: sortby(tree, c, 0))
        # adjust the column's width to the header string
        tree.column(col,
                    width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

    for item in car_list:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
        # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
        for ix, val in enumerate(item):
            col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
            if tree.column(car_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
               tree.column(car_header[ix], width=col_w)










Remplissage=parse_csv(open('Remplissage.csv','rU',encoding="ISO-8859-1").read())
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Visualizer")

container = ttk.Frame()

liste_croq = Listbox(root,width=70, height=10)
for i in range(0,len(Remplissage)):
               if Remplissage[i][0]=="Name":
                  for j in range(1,len(Remplissage[i])):
                      liste_croq.insert(i,Remplissage[i][j])
                      liste_croq.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda evt, container=container : CurSelet_croq(evt,container))
                      liste_croq.pack()


root.mainloop()
```